# How can I reduce the number of queries Doctrine is performing?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm building a product management tool where the `product` can have an arbitrary number of `attributes`, `documents`, `features`, `images`, `videos` as well as a single `type`, `brand`, and `category`. There are a few other related tables, but this is enough to demonstrate the problem.

There's a Model class called `ProductModel` that contains a method like this (reduced for clarity):

```
  public function loadValues() {
    //Product entity data
    $this->id = $this->entity->getId();
    $this->slug = $this->entity->getSlug();

    // One of each of these
    $this->loadType();
    $this->loadBrand();
    $this->loadCategory();

    // Arbitrary number of each of these
    $this->loadAttributes();
    $this->loadDocuments();
    $this->loadFeatures();
    $this->loadImages();
    $this->loadVideos();
    ...
  }
```

Each of the load methods does some boiler plate that eventually executes this method:

```
  public function loadEntitiesByProductId($productId=0) {

    // Get all the entities of this type that are associated with the product.
    $entities = $this->entityManager
      ->getRepository($this->entityName)
      ->findByProduct($productId);

    $instances = array();

    // Create a Model for each entity and load the data.
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
      $id = $entity->getId();
      $instances[$id] = new $this->childClass();
      $instances[$id]->entity = $entity;
      $instances[$id]->loadValues();
    }

    return $instances;

  }
```

This is OK for cases where the related entity is a single table, but usually it's a mapper. In those cases, I get all the mapper entities in the first query then I have to query for the related entity within the `loadValues()` method (via Doctrine's `get<Entity>()` method). The result of this process is a huge number of queries (often >100). I need to get rid of the extraneous queries, but I'd like to do so without losing the idioms I'm using across my data models.

Is there a way to get the entityManager to do a better job at using joins to group these queries?

Comment: how about [extra-lazy](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html) association? At Docs:  `Associations are marked as Lazy by default, which means the whole collection object for an association is populated the first time its accessed. If you mark an association as extra lazy the following methods on collections can be called without triggering a full load of the collection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple problems with my previous approach:

First, I was getting the entities from the repository instead of loading them from the existing entity:

```
$entities = $this->entityManager
  ->getRepository($this->entityName)
  ->findByProduct($productId);
```

Better is:

```
$method = $this->deriveGetMethod($this->entityName);
$entities = $productEntity->$method()
```

Second, I was retrieving the product entity using `$this->entityManager->getRespository...` which works fine for loading small data sets (a single table or one or two relations), but there's no way to get the repository's `findBy` methods to load relations in a single query. The solution is to use the queryBuilder.

```
$qb = $this->entityManger->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $this->select('product',/*related tables*/)->/*joins etc.*/
$productEntity = $query->getSingleResult();
```